# Initial django admin forms with data

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I've used `django-admin` and assigned a `django-form` to it. I need to fill up one of my custom rows with a random dynamic data. I can't use `initial` from form attributes BTW. I need to get the data from my `URL` and my `URL` is generated with another component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field values can be passed into a form by appending them to the form’s URL using the following structure:

```
baseURL?variable1=value
```

Replace `baseURL` with the form’s `URL`, variable1 with the variable associated with the field to be filled in and value with the appropriate field value. To fill in multiple fields, insert the ampersand symbol (&) before any additional variables:

```
baseURL?variable1=value&variable2=value
```